# Group many columns to single column and make subtraction

Tags: r, group-by, multiple-columns, stat

I have two files in txt format `A` and `B`:

File `A` contains values one below the other (`418` values).

The `B` file contains array values with `17` columns and each column contains `23` values (the values separated by a colon).

I would like to write a code in `R` that allows:

1. For file `B`: copy the columns one below the other to form a single column
2. The output file: a txt file contains the subtraction result between the column in `A` file and the resulting column in `B` file.

This operation will be repeated for several files.

[See the attached, File A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXFnr.jpg) 
 [File B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zruxb.jpg)

File A

```
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
0.190148
0.199478
0.20361
0.203169
0.201191
0.201346
0.205708
0.213419
0.221038
0.224394
0.220855
0.210688
0.196785
0.183
0.172166
0.164998
0.160437
0.157072
0.154574
0.154129
0.157576
0.165833
0.177731
```

File B

```
0.12878:0.136196:0.135554:0.13608:0.14138:0.174579:0.186398:0.256807:0.254303:0.219796:0.227208:0.204967:0.217935:0.211963:0.175196:0.234157:0.191218
0.128909:0.142429:0.128153:0.139851:0.14249:0.190176:0.173172:0.267493:0.283524:0.23515:0.233571:0.226815:0.2258:0.225029:0.181013:0.253387:0.21417
0.130535:0.142792:0.122401:0.14498:0.142571:0.197696:0.164431:0.258605:0.3002:0.246121:0.231584:0.244324:0.233801:0.230265:0.182308:0.25601:0.232748
0.132557:0.137453:0.120111:0.148618:0.141019:0.197197:0.162695:0.239687:0.302463:0.25137:0.227029:0.250412:0.242177:0.23143:0.180927:0.243387:0.245335
0.133782:0.129703:0.121407:0.148903:0.137579:0.194796:0.167493:0.224874:0.297327:0.252347:0.226346:0.243601:0.250463:0.234913:0.181163:0.222744:0.252813
0.133883:0.124062:0.125157:0.146549:0.133007:0.198916:0.176677:0.224186:0.295805:0.252501:0.232605:0.229474:0.257644:0.24504:0.187161:0.203275:0.256944
0.133738:0.123672:0.13:0.144836:0.129141:0.214668:0.188191:0.237392:0.305372:0.255212:0.243695:0.217807:0.262611:0.260563:0.200071:0.191577:0.258495
0.13489:0.128566:0.135226:0.147825:0.128186:0.23988:0.201013:0.254229:0.324588:0.261613:0.253778:0.216927:0.264611:0.274689:0.216733:0.188945:0.256424
0.138422:0.13581:0.140907:0.157792:0.131518:0.265395:0.214716:0.260835:0.343394:0.269626:0.257002:0.228643:0.263419:0.278806:0.230844:0.191816:0.248697
0.144008:0.141377:0.147269:0.173429:0.138692:0.279672:0.228195:0.248381:0.349008:0.274851:0.251085:0.246887:0.259188:0.267688:0.236057:0.194759:0.23416
0.149777:0.142563:0.153848:0.190008:0.147321:0.27507:0.238757:0.218545:0.333822:0.272862:0.238535:0.260955:0.252151:0.242955:0.229285:0.193948:0.214135
0.153174:0.139434:0.159126:0.201527:0.154004:0.2521:0.242587:0.182511:0.300373:0.261612:0.224813:0.261504:0.242456:0.212605:0.212324:0.189:0.192544
0.15235:0.134484:0.161055:0.203679:0.15589:0.219132:0.236615:0.154233:0.260276:0.242596:0.214732:0.245761:0.230295:0.186826:0.190876:0.182248:0.174302
0.147261:0.130802:0.15823:0.195977:0.152049:0.187795:0.220738:0.142276:0.227748:0.220157:0.20947:0.218908:0.216253:0.172579:0.171592:0.176303:0.162867
0.139791:0.129989:0.15099:0.181827:0.143921:0.166847:0.198906:0.145349:0.211713:0.199398:0.206162:0.190962:0.201627:0.170219:0.158879:0.171807:0.158443
0.132815:0.13121:0.141672:0.166588:0.134591:0.158168:0.178091:0.154223:0.211335:0.183958:0.200311:0.17116:0.18839:0.174108:0.153269:0.16706:0.158012
0.128714:0.131951:0.133723:0.154791:0.127314:0.157074:0.165383:0.158593:0.21762:0.174877:0.189412:0.163308:0.178726:0.17672:0.152134:0.159819:0.157265
0.12821:0.129966:0.130053:0.14813:0.124088:0.156469:0.164655:0.154331:0.219932:0.171062:0.175343:0.164776:0.174282:0.173591:0.152063:0.149945:0.153328
0.130179:0.125075:0.131543:0.145311:0.125005:0.151968:0.174619:0.146359:0.213176:0.170823:0.163854:0.169456:0.175521:0.166022:0.151281:0.140906:0.146654
0.132495:0.119582:0.136567:0.143624:0.12863:0.1447:0.189405:0.145254:0.20108:0.17335:0.161328:0.172495:0.181538:0.159918:0.150548:0.13875:0.140927
0.133362:0.11696:0.141827:0.141094:0.133035:0.14009:0.201427:0.159803:0.193559:0.179141:0.170805:0.173606:0.190467:0.161648:0.152118:0.148839:0.141013
0.132306:0.119608:0.144067:0.137789:0.136824:0.143631:0.205018:0.190363:0.199934:0.189145:0.189764:0.176801:0.200277:0.173668:0.157592:0.172201:0.150168
0.130263:0.127115:0.141712:0.135491:0.139544:0.156582:0.198918:0.227473:0.222448:0.203333:0.211166:0.186848:0.209566:0.192753:0.166266:0.203816:0.168137
```

Comment: Please show the input in reproducible form (see instructions at top of [tag:r]). and also the R code of your best attempt.

Comment: I am a beginner with R and the forum.

Comment: Hi valkrie, for us to help, we also need to reproduce the problem you have. How about trying this, have you tried to read in file A or B?

Comment: Hi StupidWolf.. How I can send the files here.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with, as well as [ask]

Comment: I added the files

Answer (score 1):

```
require(dplyr)
a <- read.table("a.txt", header =F) %>% unlist(.) %>% as.numeric()
b <- read.table("b.txt", header = F) %>% unlist(.) %>% as.numeric()
a - b
```

Comment: Hard to help more with the provided information and without the actual data

Comment: How I can add my files in the post?

Comment: dput( read.table("a.txt", header =F)) and paste the output here

Comment: the same problem, I added the files here